# How can I round a decimal up to the nearest x.x9 in C#

Tags: c#

As the title states I need to round decimal numbers up to the next 2 decimal place number ending in 9. for example:

```
1.07 -> 1.09
1.11 -> 1.19
1.99 -> 1.99
```

I have read through c#'s Math.round documentation but I have not been able to find anything that can accomplish this.

My current implementation is this:

```
x = decimal.Parse(Math.Round(x),2);
x = decimal.Parse(x.ToString().Remove(x.Length -1,1) + "9")
```

but this seems sloppy and efficiency matters as I will be processing 10s of thousands of items. There must be a better way.

Thanks

Comment: Round it up to the nearest tenth, the subtract -0.01...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - That won't work. If you started with `5` then that approach would return `4.99` (which would be a downward movement).

Comment: Pretty sure I've seen this exact question on SO before, now to search through all of the duplicates...

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm not sure what you're talking about. You seem to have read that as "round it to the nearest whole number", when in fact it says "round it **up** to the nearest **tenth**".

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan if the input is 5, rounding to the nearest tenth is 5 and 5 - 0.01 is 4.99. Also 5.1 rounded to the nearest tenth is still 5.1 and 5.1-0.01 is 5.09 and the result should be 5.19

Comment: @Gusman Math.Ceiling doesn't take 2 parameters.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - If I do `decimal n = 5m; decimal r = (Math.Ceiling(n * 10m) / 10m - 0.01m)` the result is `4.99m` - this is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can round down the number and then add 0.09:

```
Math.Floor(x * 10) / 10 + 0.09
```

Comment: This works as long as `x` is not a whole number but yeah, `Floor` is the way to go here.

Comment: @InBetween Isn't rounding 1 to 1.09 the desired behavior?

Comment: Should be noted that this only works for positive numbers.

Comment: Yes, rounding 1 to 1.09 is the desires behavior and working for only positive numbers does work for my use case.

Comment: I guess it is ;)